# Calculating equivalent height if width is resized of image in PHP

Tags: php, image, function

I am new to stackoverflow, but want to learn with the help of it.
Right now I am learning Image resizing in PHP, and stuck in a situation where Image size is 2445x1783 (width x height)

I want to make a function in PHP which can resize the image, from ratio-wise, as if the image width exceeds 1600 pixels, then resize it to 1600px width and corresponding RATIOED height.

Is there any formula for calculating the height in my case?
Thanks

Comment: this is simple math called cross multiplication http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/cross-multiply.html

Comment: Do you understand what ratios are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate the ratio and multiply the original height by it:

```
<?php
$max_width = 1600;
$new_width = $original_width; $new_height = $original_height;
if ($original_width > $max_width) {
  $ratio = $max_width / $original_width;
  $new_width = $max_width;
  $new_height = $original_height * $ratio;
}
?>
```